# Crop and merge 3 images in single ImageMagick or Convert command

Tags: merge, imagemagick, crop, imagemagick-convert

want to crop 3 regions from **picture.jpg** and join those 3 images in a single one.

Does it possible to crop and merge those 3 images in a single imagemagick or convert command?
If not possible in a single command how would be the way to merge the 3 images in separate commands?

My goal is to avoid save temporal images doing it in a single command.

I get each region with the following commands.

```
convert picture.jpg -crop 212x32+717+190 -resize 318x48! out1.jpg
convert picture.jpg -crop 440x231+20+251 -resize 660x347! out2.jpg
convert picture.jpg -crop 440x231+490+251 -resize 660x347! out3.jpg
```

- The size of output image I want to obtain would be 1336x411 pixels.
- The position of each cropped image within final output image would be:

  out1.jpg located in (x,y) = (509,0)
  out2.jpg located in (x,y) = (0,64)
  out3.jpg located in (x,y) = (676,64)

**picture.jpg**
[image: picture.jpg]

**output.jpg**
[image: output.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using IM's "convert" you can read in the original image, then "-clone" it several times within parentheses to work on copies of the input image. Inside the parentheses you can "-crop" each copy the way you want, and "-repage" them so each contains the finished canvas size and location information. After that you can "-delete" the original input, "-flatten" the three remaining images onto a single canvas, and write the output.

The command would look like this at a Windows command prompt.

```
convert input.jpg ^
   ( -clone 0 -crop 212x32+717+190 -resize 318x48! -repage 1336x411+509+0 ) ^
   ( -clone 0 -crop 440x231+20+251 -resize 660x347! -repage 1336x411+0+64 ) ^
   ( -clone 0 -crop 440x231+490+251 -resize 660x347! -repage 1336x411+676+64 ) ^
   -delete 0 -flatten output.png
```

If you're running on a *nix system you'll need to replace those continued line carets "^" with backslashes "\", and also escape the parentheses with backslashes "\( ... \)".

Comment: Excellent GeeMack!!! It works just perfect. I see that ImageMagick is so powerful. Thanks so much.

Comment: @GeeMack Any ideas how to `-clone` inside Node child-process? Like `spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, ...do cloning..., tempLocalFile])`?

Comment: @Igniter - I have no idea how to do that. You might do well to post it as a new question where people with more expertise can give you better replies.